# Update embedded array document with Mongoose using req.body

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, patch, embedded-resource

I have a collection of users and a document can be as follows...

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('this user id'),
  firstName: 'first name of this user',
  lastName: 'last name of this user',
  tvs: [
    {
      _id: ObjectId('this tv id'),
      brand: 'This tv brand',
      size: 'this tv size',
    },
    {
      _id: ObjectId('this other tv id'),
      brand: 'this other tv brand',
      size: 'this other tv size',
    }
  ]
}
```

I am having trouble trying to update a document embedded in the array of `tvs` using only `req.body`. I managed to be able to update the document based on the tv id by doing the following...

```
await User.updateOne(
    {
      _id: req.user.id,
      'tvs._id': req.params.id,
    },
    {
      $set: { 'tvs.$.brand': req.body.brand },
    }
  );
```

but what I want to do is something like this...

```
await User.updateOne(
    {
      _id: req.user.id,
      'tvs._id': req.params.id,
    },
    {
      $set: { 'tvs.$': req.body },
    }
  );
```

where `req.body` can have many fields and will only update the fields specified and leave the other ones untouched. Problem is that when I do this it changes my element to have only the `id` and whatever fields I may have in `req.body` and gets rid of all the other fields.

Comment: In your schema `tvs` is an array but `req.body` is an object. How do you want to update an array with an object? What element into the array do you want to update?

Comment: Actually, I just solved it. I might have butchered what I meant to say but basically I created a new empty obj and updated that object to have all the fields and associated values of the request body, however, this new object will have all fields starting with `tvs.$.fieldname` where `fieldname` is the current field being looked at when iterating through all the keys in `req.body`. Then for the update I do `$set: newObj`. I was hoping there would be another way but this is what I have so far

Comment: I do not want to change my array in an object itself but update an object in my array with the fields coming from the request body without having to specify the fields such as `tvs.$.brand` but instead `tvs.$: req.body`. This changes fields that I do not want updated to not be there anymore. By doing what I mentioned in my previous comment I was able to solve this issue but still wondering if I can do this in a different way